# Access Violation at SwapChain.Present

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I have a very annoying problem at the following lines of code:

```
try{
  mSwapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);    //AccessViolationException, caught by debugger
}catch(Exception Ex){
  throw Ex;  //Debugstop here, but not reached
}

//DeviceContext: SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext
//mVertexBinding: SharpDX.Direct3D11.VertexBufferBinding

DeviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, mVertexBinding);
DeviceContext.Draw(mNumVertices, 0);
```

My program runs a timer which raises an event, if it is raised and i'm not rendering at this time, the program forces a rendercall. There runs another timer + mouse events at the same time, updating matrices, vertices, buffers and stuff - but while rendering, all those update functions are locked - but only until `DeviceContext.Draw(mNumVertices, 0);` is reached, after this, the syncing object gets unlocked.

My question now - can the access violation be raised if `VertexBufferBinding` is changed between `Draw(..)` and `SwapChain.Present(..)` ? Or is it copied ?
And, secound one - why can't i catch this access violation? It's always an "Unhandled exception".

Edit: Strange thing is, that the access violation only appears on my Work Notebook (Core i5, Intel HD 3000 & Radeon 6490M) but not on my Home Laptop (Core i7, Intel HD 3000 & NVidia GeForce 540M).

Comment: Looking at the documentation of SwapChain.Present: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153037(v=vs.85).aspx It looks like that function does not throw an AccessViolationException, so the problem comes from somewhere else I assume.

Comment: what is the call stack of the access violation?

Comment: Humm.. you're right.. i've searched in the sharpdx code, but i think its an auto generated function.. and i haven't got any information on the call stack, because it's "external code"... more testing shows me, that the access violation appears mostly, if the matrices of camera/object are often changed..

Comment: @jeroenh : > BeatCore.dll!BeatCore.DirectX.Common.DxProvider.Swap() Line 283 C#
  PaperCraft.exe!PaperCraft.MainWindow.Render() Line 354 + 0xf Bytes C#
  [External Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing, it points out that this problem must be caused by the amd dynamic switchable graphics option - with integrated or maximum graphics forced, the exception does not appear, so maybe it is when the amd driver changes the gpu setting for the application - like docs says, "gpu will be dynamically switched if more power is required". So it wasn't because i updated some matrices or vertices, it was because of the more power my program needs when this operations are done (it is a little cad/modelling program with hierarchical geometry - when A1 is updated, AX to AZ have to be recalculated too).

And, maybe, it happens not on an NVidia System, because the gpu is not dynamically switched - it is set at application startup time.